Tangentbundle of submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$
Let $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $k$-dim submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I want to prove that the tangent bundle of $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$. The idea is: Since $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$, it is especially locally a regular submanifold, i.e. $\forall x\in M,$ there is a neighbourhood $x\in U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and an embedding $\psi:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ such that $U\cap M=\psi^{-1}(0)$. I want to prove thet $TM$ is also locally a regular submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. But I can't find such an embedding.
Also, how should I understand the tangent bundle in this case? It is offically defined as $TM=\bigcup_{x\in M}T_xM$, and (by my definition) the tangent space is $T_xM=\{x\}\times\Sigma_x$ where $\Sigma_x$ is the tangent plane at this point. But in this case why we can't just say $TM=M\times \mathbb{R}^k$ and let the product give it the manifold structure?

Are you trying to prove that the total space of the tangent bundle is diffeomorphic to a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$? Then it is absolutely false, try to find a counter-example (hint: $\dim TM =2k$).


You can't, because it's generally not true: The dimension of $TM$ as a manifold is $2 \dim M$, and there is no reason to suppose that $2 \dim M \leq n$. 2. It is not surprising that you cannot find any embeddings of the form $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n - k}$ unless $k = 0$: There are none. 3. "why can't we just say $TM = M \times \mathbb{R}^k$" because it's generally wrong. The notation $TM = \bigcup_{x \in M} T_x M$ is a bit misleading, because it hides that the underlying topology is generally not the product topology.


You should indeed be proving that $TM$ is a submanifold of $M\times\Bbb R^n\subset\Bbb R^{2n}$. Perhaps working with local parametrizations would be better than working with local level sets. (For the normal bundle, your tactic is better.)

@MoisheKohan Sorry, I've just edited my question. I want to prove the total space is a submanifold of a proper euclidean space (I know now it should be submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$)

What is a "proper Euclidean space?"

@MoisheKohan I just mean I should prove that there is an $m\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $TM$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^m$. Now directly speaking I need to prove that $TM$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

@BenSteffan Could you please explain more about third point? I think as set, TM and $M\times \mathbb{R}^k$ are the same, and the topology of both of them are given by the usual Euclidean topology, because they are both open subset of euclidean space.

@TedShifrin Maybe do you know some methods for this? I have seen some constructions with local parametrizations for a general smooth manifold, not just for a submanifold of euclidean space, but I think for submanifold of euclidean space there should be something much easier than the construction of $TM$ of a general manifold

@GaoMinghao As sets they are the same, that is right. But they are not in any way open subsets of Euclidean space a priori. As has been pointed out above, what you're trying to do here simply doesn't work: If $M$ lives inside $\mathbb{R}^n$ this does not imply that its tangent bundle does as well, and even if it did you would need to know what the topology (and smooth structure) on the tangent bundle was in the first place to talk about embeddings.

Charts are the inverse maps of parametrizations. Now you have local diffeomorphisms $\phi_\alpha\colon U_\alpha\to V_\alpha\subset M\subset \Bbb R^n$, where $U_\alpha\subset \Bbb R^k$ is open.

Thanks to all of you, and I've write an answer below. Could someone please help me briefly check the correctness of this proof?

Locally, a submanifold of $\bf R^n$ is just the graph of a function $f: R^d\to R^{n-d}$ (after changing the order of coordinates, if necessary). In the neigbourhood of a fixed point the tangent bundle is the graph of the function $R^d\times R^b \to R^{n-d}\times R^{n-d}$ given by $F(x,u)=(f(x), f'(x).u)$. Therefore, it is also a manifold. Here $f'(x) $ is a linear map from $\bf R^d$ to $ R^{n-d}$, or a matrix of partial derivatives if you prefer. Note that is $f$ is $C^k$, $F$ is $C^{k-1}$, so the tangent bundle is only a $C^{k-1}$-submanifold.

Suppose $ M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ is a $ k $-dimensional submanifold, and $ x \in M $. The tangent space $ T_xM $ at $ x $ in Euclidean space is simply defined as the tangent plane through $ x $, denoted by $ T_xM = (x, \Sigma_x) \subseteq \{x\} \times \mathbb{R}^n $, which is a $ k $-dimensional linear subspace of $ \mathbb{R}^n $ ($ \mathbb{R}^k \cong \Sigma_x \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $). Define
$$
TM := \bigcup_{x \in M} T_xM = \{(x, \Sigma_x) \mid x \in M, \Sigma_x \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n\} \subseteq M \times \mathbb{R}^n \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
Therefore, we see that the set $ TM $ is a subset of $ \mathbb{R}^{2n} $. We first endow $ TM $ with the structure of a smooth manifold. To this end, we recall that every submanifold of Euclidean space is locally a regular level set (and vice versa). Since $ M $ is a $ k $-dimensional manifold, let $ x \in M $ and $ v \in T_xM $. Then there exists an open neighborhood $ U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ of $ x $ and a map $ \psi: U \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k} $, such that $ U \cap M = \psi^{-1}(0) $, and $ 0 $ is a regular value of $ \psi $. For any $ y \in U \cap M $, since $ U \cap M $ as an open subset of the smooth manifold $ M $ is still a smooth manifold, and by previous discussions on the tangent spaces of submanifolds as regular level sets, we have $ \forall y \in U \cap M: T_yM = T_y(U \cap M) = \text{Ker} \psi_{*,y} $ (the first equality is obvious, since these are submanifolds of Euclidean space, and the tangent planes of two intersecting manifolds are the same). Define
$$
\Psi: U \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n-k} \times \mathbb{R}^{n-k}, \quad (z, v) \mapsto (\psi(z), J(\psi)_z(v)),
$$
where $ J(\psi)_z $ is the Jacobian matrix of $ \psi $ at $ z $. Since $ \psi $ is smooth, it is evident that $ \Psi $ is also smooth. We claim that $ \Psi(z, v) = 0 \Leftrightarrow z \in M \cap U $ and $ v \in T_z(M \cap U) $. Because: “$ \Rightarrow $”: If $ \Psi(z, v) = 0 $, then by definition $ \psi(z) = 0 $ and $ \psi_{*,z}(v) = 0 $. Since $ U \cap M = \psi^{-1}(0) $, we have $ z \in U \cap M \subseteq M $. Also, since $ \forall y \in U \cap M $ we have $ T_y(M \cap U) = \text{Ker} \psi_{*,y} $, it follows from $ \psi_{*,z}(v) = 0 $ that $ v \in \text{Ker} \psi_{*,z} = T_z(M \cap U) $. “$ \Leftarrow $”: Similarly. Hence, we know that $ \Psi^{-1}(0) = \{(z, v) \mid z \in M \cap U, v \in T_z(M \cap U)\} $. Since $ M \cap U \subseteq M $ is a submanifold of $ M $, we can write it as $ \{(z, v) \mid z \in M \cap U, v \in T_z(M \cap U)\} = TM \big|_{M \cap U} $. Therefore, we see that locally around the point $ (x, v) \in TM \big|_{M \cap U} \subseteq TM $, we have $ TM \big|_{M \cap U} = \Psi^{-1}(0) $. Hence, $ TM $ can be locally written as a level set (whether it is regular or not is yet to be determined). However, since $ \Psi $ is a map between subsets of Euclidean spaces, its differential (Jacobian matrix) is easy to compute. First, we write this multivariable function more precisely as
$$
\Psi: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \ni (x, y) \mapsto (\psi_1(x), \ldots, \psi_{n-k}(x); \sum_{i=1}^n (\partial_{x_i} \psi_1 \big|_x) \cdot y_i, \ldots, \sum_{i=1}^n (\partial_{x_i} \psi_{n-k} \big|_x) \cdot y_i),
$$
thus the Jacobian matrix's upper left $(n-k) \times n$ block is exactly the Jacobian matrix of $ \psi $, and the upper right $(n-k) \times n$ block is zero (since $ \frac{\partial \psi_i (x)}{\partial y_j} = 0 $), we do not care about the lower left $(n-k) \times n$ block, and the lower right $(n-k) \times n$ block needs a bit of calculation: the $(n-k) \times n$ matrix's $ i $-th row $ j $-th column (i.e., the $(n-k+i)$-th row $ n+j $-th column of the whole matrix) is
$$
\frac{\partial \Psi_{n-k+i}}{\partial y_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} \sum_{m=1}^n (\partial_{x_m} \psi_i \big|_x) \cdot y_m = \sum_{m=1}^n \left[ \underbrace{\frac{\partial (\partial_{x_m} \psi_i \big|_x)}{\partial y_j}}_{=0} \cdot y_j + \frac{\partial \psi_i}{\partial x_m} \bigg|_x \cdot \underbrace{\frac{\partial y_m}{\partial y_j}}_{=\delta_{mj}} \right] = \frac{\partial \psi_i}{\partial x_j} \bigg|_x = (J(\psi)_x)_{i,j}.
$$
Therefore, we find that this matrix has a block form: both the upper left and lower right $(n-k) \times n$ submatrices are the Jacobian matrix of $ \psi $, and the upper right $(n-k) \times n$ submatrix is zero. So, $ \forall q = (q_1, q_2) \in (M \cap U, T_z(M \cap U)) $, we have
$$
\Psi_{*,q} = \begin{pmatrix}
J(\psi)_{q_1} & 0 \\
* & J(\psi)_{q_1}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since $ q_1 \in M \cap U $, $ q_1 $ is a regular point of $ \psi $, thus $ \text{rank} J(\psi)_{q_1} = n-k $ (full rank), and thus $ \Psi_{*,q} $ is also of full rank, indicating that $ \Psi $ is an immersion. Since we are in Euclidean space, the restricted map $ \Psi $ is obviously a homeomorphism. Thus, $ TM $ is locally a regular level set. At each point locally, the regular level set provides a local diffeomorphism, thereby obtaining a smooth atlas globally, becoming a smooth manifold of dimension $ 2n - 2(n-k) = 2k $. Hence, the projection $ \pi: TM \to M $ as the restriction of $ \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n $ is smooth. Next, we prove that $ TM $ has a local trivialization. Consider a local coordinate chart $ (\Omega, \varphi) $ around $ x \in M $. Define
$$
\phi: TM\big|_{\Omega} \to \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^k, \quad (x, v) \mapsto (\varphi(x), J(\varphi)_x \cdot v)
$$
This map provides a diffeomorphism $ TM\big|_{\Omega} = \pi^{-1}(\Omega) \to \Omega \times \mathbb{R}^k $, i.e., a local trivilization.
Therefore, $ \pi: TM \to M $ is a vector bundle over $ M $.
It is important not to confuse $ TM $ with $ TM \cong M \times \mathbb{R}^k $; this is not valid. Note that the tangent bundle as a set is defined as $ \bigcup_{x \in M} T_xM = \bigcup_{x \in M} (x, \Sigma_x) $. We can only say that $ TM \subseteq M \times \mathbb{R}^n $, but we cannot say that $ TM \cong M \times \mathbb{R}^k $, even though $ \Sigma_x \cong \mathbb{R}^k $. According to the definition of the tangent bundle, we indeed have $ TM = \bigcup_x \{(x, \Sigma_x) \mid x \in M\} $, but if we identify $ \{(x, \Sigma_x) \mid x \in M\} \cong M \times \mathbb{R}^k $, this would mean we are considering all tangent spaces to be the same $ \Sigma_x = \Sigma_y $ for all $ x \neq y \in M $. However, obviously they should not be the same, $ \Sigma_x $ and $ \Sigma_y $ intersect in $ \mathbb{R}^n $ forming a lower-dimensional subspace. Although we can endow $ M \times \mathbb{R}^k $ with a smooth manifold structure via the product manifold, there is no diffeomorphism $ M \times \mathbb{R}^k \to TM $ to transfer the structure of $ M \times \mathbb{R}^k $ to $ TM $. Therefore, we must put in some effort to prove that the tangent bundle is a smooth manifold.
